# function has no attribute all

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

i am getting this attribute error (function has no attribute all) when i clicked on a question in my browser after running my server. I have gone through the code many times but couldn't find the error.
View.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name ='pulls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
    
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
    Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
    published in the future).
    """
        
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


    
#Detail Function
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name ='pulls/detail.html'
    
    def queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

Comment: Can you add the error stacktrace ?

Comment: AttributeError at /pulls/1/
'function' object has no attribute 'all'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pulls/1/
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'function' object has no attribute 'all'
Exception Location: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py, line 77, in get_queryset

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), the `generic.DetailView` inherits methods and attributes from 5 views, including `SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin` and `BaseDetailView`.

[`BaseDetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.BaseDetailView) is a base view for displaying a single object... .

So, if you are showing more than one object it is better that do not use `DetailView`. Otherwise, as it is written in the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/detail.py#L179), you should override `self.get_object()`.